# Обновление состояния прогрессбара с помощью jQuery .animate()

Tags: jquery, animate, анимация, javascript

Доброй ночи! У меня есть такой блок кода:

```
// Вывод процентов, вида 99.99%, на поле прогресс бара!
var myPer = 0;
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: myPer
}).children('.ui-progressbar-value').html(myPer.toPrecision(3) + '%').css({
    display: 'block',
    align: 'center',
    fontColor: 'red',
});
```

Этот блок кода выводит на ПрогрессБаре 0.00%. Задача - Мне нужно каждые **8640мс** добавлять по 0.01% + 0.00%, пока общая сумма не будет равна 100.00%. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу, а то к ночи мозг уже не работает, к сожалению ;-( С помощью метода **.animate()**, но не обязательно...

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста, решить поставленную задачу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно вот [так](http://jsfiddle.net/oneboy/Asbf4/1/), например... ну только поменять 1000 на 8640...

```
<div class="progress"></div>
```

-

```
var val =  0.00;

$('.progress').progressbar({value: val });

function updateProgress() {
    val += 0.01;
    $('.progress')
        .progressbar({value:val})
        .children('.ui-progressbar-value')
        .html(val.toFixed(2) + '%')
        .css({
            display: 'block',
            align: 'center',
            fontColor: 'red',
            });            
    if(val < 100)
        setTimeout(updateProgress, 1000);
}

setTimeout(updateProgress, 1000);  ​
```

​

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 2):

Еще можно аналогично, только поменять `setTimeout` на `setInterval` и не забыть про `clearInterval`

А по поводу `$().animate()` ВООБЩЕ - почитайте про css3 transitions, это много круче